# Add missing months in Record Set

Tags: sql-server

Could you please help me to generate results as in below request?

I have generated a result set but in my data few months have no data and so, therefore, no months are displaying in recordset but I want to display all those months where there is no data.

Please see attached image and I also have attached result script to work easily on this.

[image]

```
Create Table #TempTbl(
    [Year]    int,
    [Month]   int,
    LostQty   int,
    WonQty    int,
    LostValue int,
    WonValue  int,
)

GO

INSERT INTO #TempTbl VALUES (2015, 3, 13, 6, 3000,4500),
                            (2015,  4,  1,  1,  4000, 200),
                            (2015,  5,  0,  1,  0,  200),
                            (2015,  6,  4,  6,  5000,   3000),
                            (2015,  7,  1,  2,  3500,   1100),
                            (2015,  8,  1,  1,  2000,   900),
                            (2015,  9,  5,  0,  2500,   0),
                            (2015,  10, 6,  3,  4500,   800),
                            (2015,  11, 0,  1,  0,  7400),
                            (2015,  12, 1,  0,  2200,   0),
                            (2016,  1,  3,  5,  2200,   200),
                            (2016,  2,  0,  1,  0,  1500),
                            (2016,  3,  1,  0,  2300,   0),
                            (2016,  4,  1,  0,  3500,   0),
                            (2016,  9,  4,  1,  1500,   1400),
                            (2016,  10, 16, 4,  1700,   3000),
                            (2016,  11, 5,  5,  500,    400),
                            (2016,  12, 6,  0,  600,    0)
```

Comment: just add a calendar table, populate it, and left join it with your table. use ifnull(value,0)

Comment: Thank Horaciux it working now

Comment: I'm glad it helps, I was on the phone, hard to code from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a permanent Calendar table is extremely helpful for lots of different tasks but there are times when adding new objects simply isn't feasible. In that situation, it is quite easy to build one on the fly.

Note... In this solution, I used the base table to query the years, but it isn't necessary (or even desirable) to do so... Just something to keep in mind...

```
WITH 
    cte_Calendar AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            tt.[year],
            m.[Month]
        FROM
            #TempTbl tt
            CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12) ) m ([Month])
        )
SELECT 
    c.[Year], c.[Month], tt.LostQty, tt.WonQty, tt.LostValue, tt.WonValue
FROM
    #TempTbl tt
    FULL JOIN cte_Calendar c
        ON tt.[Year] = c.[Year]
        AND tt.[Month] = c.[Month]
ORDER BY 
    c.[Year],
    c.[Month];
```

And the results...

```
Year        Month       LostQty     WonQty      LostValue   WonValue
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2015        1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
2015        2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
2015        3           13          6           3000        4500
2015        3           13          6           3000        4500
2015        4           1           1           4000        200
2015        4           1           1           4000        200
2015        5           0           1           0           200
2015        5           0           1           0           200
2015        6           4           6           5000        3000
2015        6           4           6           5000        3000
2015        7           1           2           3500        1100
2015        7           1           2           3500        1100
2015        8           1           1           2000        900
2015        8           1           1           2000        900
2015        9           5           0           2500        0
2015        9           5           0           2500        0
2015        10          6           3           4500        800
2015        10          6           3           4500        800
2015        11          0           1           0           7400
2015        11          0           1           0           7400
2015        12          1           0           2200        0
2015        12          1           0           2200        0
2016        1           3           5           2200        200
2016        1           3           5           2200        200
2016        2           0           1           0           1500
2016        2           0           1           0           1500
2016        3           1           0           2300        0
2016        3           1           0           2300        0
2016        4           1           0           3500        0
2016        4           1           0           3500        0
2016        5           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
2016        6           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
2016        7           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
2016        8           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
2016        9           4           1           1500        1400
2016        9           4           1           1500        1400
2016        10          16          4           1700        3000
2016        10          16          4           1700        3000
2016        11          5           5           500         400
2016        11          5           5           500         400
2016        12          6           0           600         0
2016        12          6           0           600         0
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. :)